# Number of possible values of $x$ if $817252xy$ is divisible by $11$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$A=817252xy$

Find number of possible value of $x$ if $A$ is divisible by $11$

I applied the divisibility by $11$ concept
which gave me $y−x−15=11k$
with an integer $k$ and
$0 \leq x,y \leq 9$

$y-x-15$

Answer is $9$

Comment: I think there is a typo in your equation, it's not an equation.

Comment: It's the unit-ten's place value @pjs36

Comment: But $y - x - 15$ isn't an equation (it's an expression), that's all I mean.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post. Also, this page may be of use to you: codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php.

Comment: *What* don't you understand?

Comment: Just remember to write code inside the dollar signs, for example do not write \frac{1}{2} but write $\frac{1}{2}$ - otherwise your code will not be interpreted.

Comment: Sorry for interrupting your conversation.

Comment: it must be $$y-x-15=11k$$ with an integer $k$ and $$0\le x,y\le 9$$

Comment: Can anyone help me out? I'm sorry it won't happen again from my next question

Comment: Yes @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: $$x=7,y=0$$ then we have $$0-7-15=-22$$

Comment: Didn't get what you are saying @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Answer (score 1):

The divisibility criterion is  written here as
$$y+5\equiv x+9\mod 11\iff y\equiv x+4,$$
under the constraints $0\le x,y\le 9$. The solutions are
$$xy=04,15,26,37,48,59.$$

Comment: Why did you miss out $70$, $81$, and $92$ for $xy$? There would indeed be nine solutions if you include these three.

Comment: @AT1089: I don't remember. Maybe a copy-paste accident… Thank you for pointing the problem anyway!